# What's the meaning 'filtering',and 'chain'

Tags: relations

What's the meaning 'filtering' and 'chain'? It's about of partially ordered sets.  And can you please give me any example?

**Definitions**:

1. A preordered set $(I, \leq)$ is *directed* if every finite subset $F$ of $I$ has an upper bound.
2. A subset $J$ of a preordered set $(I, \leq)$ is said to be *cofinal* if for all $i \in I$ there exists $j \in J$ such that $j \geq i$.
3. A map $f : H \to I$ between two preordered spaces is said to be *filtering* if for all $i \in I$ there exists $h \in H$ such that $f(k) \geq i$ whenever $k \in H$ satisfies $k \geq h$.
4. A subset $C$ of $(X, \leq)$ that is totally ordered for the induced preorder is called a *chain*.

Comment: The meaning is in the definition. What is unclear to you?

Comment: Yes, i do.Especially, I need some examples of each such terms

Comment: If you want, you can take trivial examples. If you explain what are your doubts, or if you tell us in what context you have seen these definitions, it will be easier to give appropriate examples instead of trivial ones.

Comment: OK.The following is a matter that I want to solves.shall you to help.please.

Comment: 1. Show that a subset C of a preordered space (X, ≤) is a chain if and only if
C × C ⊂ A ∪ A−1, where A := {(x, y) : x ≤ y}, A−1 := {(x, y) : (y, x) ∈ A}.
2. Let (I, ≤) be a directed set. Show that if J ⊂ I is not cofinal, then I \ J is cofinal.